# Laravel 4.2 - ReflectionException (-1)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am getting following error:

```
ReflectionException (-1)

Class PhotosController does not exist
```

This is my route:

```
Route::resource('photos', ' PhotosController');
```

When I change to **Route::get('photos', 'PhotosController@index');** it is working fine, but using **resource** it is falling? What is going on?
PhotosController:

```
<?php

class PhotosController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * GET /photos
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Photo::all();
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     * GET /photos/create
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     * POST /photos
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     * GET /photos/{id}
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     * GET /photos/{id}/edit
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     * PUT /photos/{id}
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     * DELETE /photos/{id}
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help. Error is still there.

Comment: Have you tried clearing both `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan dump-autoload` one right after the other?

Answer (score 1):

If `composer dump-autoload` doesn't fix it, then it is probably a typo in the class name or routes file, or incorrectly using subdirectories/namespaces on your controllers.