# Reflection Exception with message Class dashController not exist?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I had created one small application in laravel 4, after done with all code i put it on live without using composer, just copy and paste all local code with some configuration change. after that login and logout page is working fine but when i redirect user to dashboard its give following error

```
ReflectionException (-1)
```

Class dashboardController does not exist

Comment: Are you using Windows to develop your application locally?

Comment: yes i am using windows 8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428645/laravel-4-2-reflectionexception-1

Comment: what to do with this link? that question is also not solved

Comment: and by the way same files are working fine in my local machine so any other configuration need to change or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using Windows, and it works locally, but not on your server, then the problem will be a "case sensitively" issue.

Class "`dashboardController`" is incorrect. The filename is probably "`DashboardController.php`" (with a capital D) - so change your code to use a Captial D for `DashboardController` , and should work.